# matplotlib: colour bar resizing image?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm assuming I have a really simple question, which has been driving me insane for the past hour. So, I am trying to produce a contour plot with the following axis lengths x=37,y=614. I can produce a contour plot no problem, but when I add a colour bar the image becomes resized to what i'm assuming is the size of the colour bar.

Image without colour bar:

[image]

Image with colour bar:
[image]

The figure becomes resized and I do not know why.
How can I plot a figure like my first figure but with the colour scheme of the second figure and with a colour bar?

code:

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pylab


y = np.arange(1, 615)
x = np.arange(1, 37)

z = np.loadtxt('145_contact_matrix_605.txt')


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
CS = ax.contour(x, y, z)
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)


# COLOUR BAR CODE
im_out = ax.imshow(z, cmap=cm.jet)
ax.matshow(z,cmap=plt.cm.jet)
axcolor = fig.add_axes([0.9,0.1,0.02,0.8]) # adjust these vaules to position colour bar
pylab.colorbar(im_out, cax=axcolor)

plt.show()
```

Comment: very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917836/matplotlib-stretches-histogram2d-vertically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `imshow` command that's changing the aspect ratio of the axes, not the colorbar.

`imshow` assumes you want an aspect ratio of 1.0 so that a square in data coordinates will appear square (i.e. square pixels).

If you want it to behave like `contour`, the just specify `aspect='auto'`.

```
ax.imshow(z, cmap=cm.jet)
```

You should also remove the `ax.matshow` line (or use it instead of `imshow`).  As it is, you'll have two images that partially overlap and hide each other.

If you do decide to use `matshow` instead of `imshow`, you'll need to specify `aspect='auto'` for it, as well.